# How to implement an ordered list on JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2

This is the plain HTML text and used for jQuery UI theme (selectable) . However, I need to transform it to use in JSF. List items should be got back from a bean and generate an ordered-list. Is there a way to do this with JSF tags (for ex./ h:selectOneListbox)?

```
<ol class="planList" >
   <li class="ui-widget-content">plan1</li>
   <li class="ui-widget-content">plan2</li>
   <li class="ui-widget-content">plan3</li>
</ol>
```

All feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it in this way as there is no standard JSF component for this , probably because it can be done simply using `ui:repeat`

```
<ol class="planList">
<ui:repeat value="#{myManagedBean.plans}" var="plan">
<li class="ui-widget-content"><h:outputText value="#{plan.name}"/></li>
</ui:repeat>
</ol>
```